# Automator help: Creating Sub-folder From the Finder items

Tags: automator, folders

Can you help with this process of creating a sub-folders from results of "get folder contents"?

When we do the finder items, we get all the folder items. In my setup, it's creating a folder on the root folder of the finder items folder.

I"m looking for a way to create a subfolder here.

Before:

```
├── city1
└── city2
```

After:

```
├── city1
│   └── helloworld
└── city2
    └── helloworld
```

[image]

Comment: To me anyway, it is not totally clear what it is you're trying to accomplish. If what you're trying/wanting to do is create a _subfolder_ in every _subfolder_ within a given _folder_, then IMO it's easier to do it in **Terminal** using the `find` _command_ with the `-exec` _option_ and `mkdir` _command_. First _change directory_ to the target, e.g. `cd /path/to/ri` then use e.g.: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '[[:alnum:]]*' -exec mkdir {}'/Hello World' \;`  --- Change `Hello World` to the name of the _subdirectory_ to be created.

Comment: Hey budddy, thanks for the comment.. I was just trying to create a folder inside the folders (which I got from the Finder content) 

Hey, thanks for the code, it works. 

Can we make code start running from max depth 2 instead of 1? That will be very helpful.

Comment: You said "Can we make code start running from max depth 2 instead of 1?", and frankly without proper context, I do not know what it is you are asking.

Comment: To try and address your comment, if you have a _folder_, e.g. `ri` and the _subfolders_ within this _folder_ have a _subfolder_ and you want to create the new _folder_ there, then yes this can be done in **Terminal** by _change directory_ to the target, e.g. `cd /path/to/ri` then use e.g. `find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -depth 2 -exec mkdir {}'/Hello World' \;` --- Change `Hello World` to the name of the _subdirectory_ to be created.

Comment: Apologies for not asking it without proper tree graph.

Thanks, @user3439894 I did implement your second code of creating folders inside the folder at level 2. This is the final results I got. 

I owe you a beer, mate :) 

cd to ri folder 
.
├── barrington
│   └── Hello\ World123
│       └── Hello\ World
├── block-island
│   └── Hello\ World123
│       └── Hello\ World

ankii Sure, My first plan was to automate the folder structure with the Automator. but user3439894 helped me the easiest way.